# Spark Structured Streaming Watermark issue

Tags: python, pyspark, streaming, watermark

I'm trying to do a simple stream with the following code. My input is a random book for which I count number of unique words in it. After this, I want to save the output to a file.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode, col, regexp_extract, lower

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Streaming").getOrCreate()


book = spark.readStream.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).text("/FileStore/tables/another_books/")

output = (book
          .select(split(col("value"), " ").alias("line"))
          .select(explode(col("line")).alias("word"))
          .select(lower(col("word")).alias("word"))
          .select(regexp_extract(col("word"), "[a-z']*", 0).alias("word"))
          .where(col("word") != "")
          .groupby(col("word")).count()
         )

streamingQuery = (output
                  .writeStream
                  .outputMode("append")
                  .format("json")
                  .option("path", "/FileStore/tables/outputStream")
                  .option("checkpointLocation", "/FileStore/tables/checkpointLocation")
                  .start()
                  .awaitTermination()
                 )
```

This code doesn't work becasue of this error:
***AnalysisException:** Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;*

I tried to add **withWatermark**('time', '10 minutes') before **groupby** operation however the code still doesn't work...

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Try this? 
output = (book
          .select(split(col("value"), " ").alias("line"))
          .select(explode(col("line")).alias("word"))
          .select(lower(col("word")).alias("word"))
          .select(regexp_extract(col("word"), "[a-z']*", 0).alias("word"))
          .where(col("word") != "")
          .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes")  # Define watermark for 10 minutes of processing time
          .groupBy(window(col("timestamp"), "10 minutes"), col("word"))  # Group by window and word
          .count()
         )

Comment: got the following:
AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `timestamp` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`word`];

Comment: In your case, don’t you want to use outputMode(‘complete’) instead of implementing withWatermark?

And in the case of using withWatermark, ‘time’ in (‘time’, ‘10 minutes’) has be an actual field in your output stream.  Make sense?